# How can I mute the specific sounds of my phone via ADB?

Tags: audio, operating-system, mute

When my phone reproduces some specific sounds, it turns off. The sound on the startup also makes the phone turn off. So I want to mute via PC, but I got confused with that ADB stuff.

I was trying to change it using ADB on recovery mode, but it is a separate OS and doesn't affect the main one.

How can I mute the specific sounds of my phone via PC?

Comment: Are you sure it turns off at startup? Does it just require a  pin entry? If so, this is normal. What causes the sounds that makes it turn off. What is the brand and model of your phone

Comment: Some background on this question: it was first posted on SO where some more details are included what "Dump" is trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77807839/150978

Comment: Is ADB activated on your device? If yes you could connect via adb while the phone is still booting, as ADB is started early in the boot process. Unfortunately enabling e.g. Do No Disturb mode via adb doesn't seem to be possible: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188720/2241 (on my Pixel 4a DnD mode is "zen_mode 1")

Comment: @RohitGupta
The phone is a Moto G9 and the startup sound is the "hello moto". Turn off before the pin stuff

Comment: @Robert

I tried to connect my phone with ADB when it was booting, but couldn't find the device, so probably it isn't active. But yeah, I will just use a spare old phone and take the other to repair.

Thanks all and sorry to bother.